# Unable to gracefully shutdown a docker process

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I want to be able to shutdown a docker process gracefully. I derived the these files by following the idea in this blog post: https://husobee.github.io/golang/ecs/2016/05/19/ecs-graceful-go-shutdown.html

Here are my files

1) Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:jessie
ADD app /app
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y golang
CMD ["go", "run", "/app/main.go"]
```

2) app/main.go

```
package main

import "os"
import "syscall"
import "fmt"
import "time"
import "os/signal"


func main() {
    // create a "returnCode" channel which will be the return code of the application
    var returnCode = make(chan int)

    // finishUP channel signals the application to finish up
    var finishUP = make(chan struct{})

    // done channel signals the signal handler that the application has completed
    var done = make(chan struct{})

    // gracefulStop is a channel of os.Signals that we will watch for -SIGTERM
    var gracefulStop = make(chan os.Signal)

    // watch for SIGTERM and SIGINT from the operating system, and notify the app on
    // the gracefulStop channel
    signal.Notify(gracefulStop, syscall.SIGTERM)
    signal.Notify(gracefulStop, syscall.SIGINT)

    // launch a worker whose job it is to always watch for gracefulStop signals
    go func() {
        // wait for our os signal to stop the app
        // on the graceful stop channel
        // this goroutine will block until we get an OS signal
        sig := <-gracefulStop
        fmt.Printf("caught sig: %+v", sig)

        // send message on "finish up" channel to tell the app to
        // gracefully shutdown
        finishUP<-struct{}{}

        // wait for word back if we finished or not
        select {
        case <-time.After(30*time.Second):
            // timeout after 30 seconds waiting for app to finish,
            // our application should Exit(1)
            returnCode<-1
        case <-done:
            // if we got a message on done, we finished, so end app
            // our application should Exit(0)
            returnCode<-0
        }
    }()


    // ... Do business Logic in goroutines

    fmt.Println("waiting for finish")
    // wait for finishUP channel write to close the app down
    <-finishUP
    fmt.Println("stopping things, might take 2 seconds")

    // ... Do business Logic for shutdown simulated by Sleep 2 seconds
    time.Sleep(2*time.Second)

    // write to the done channel to signal we are done.
    done <-struct{}{}
    os.Exit(<-returnCode)
}
```

I build the image by running

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker-shutdown .
```

I start a container by

```
docker run  docker-shutdown
```

Then I try to shut it down by

```
docker stop <container id>
```

In the console that runs 'docker run', I can see:

```
waiting for finish
```

and it just terminated with no further output.

I would expect to see at least some output like

```
 caught sig <SIGNAL_VALUE>
```

So why my expected behavior did not happen? I am also new to `go` so I am not sure if it may have something to do with the `go` code or the `CMD` definition in the `Dockerfile`.

My question:

Why the `go` process cannot catch the either **TERM** and **KILL** signals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`go run` is getting the signal, not the program that is being run.

Compile the program ahead of time and run the binary directly in docker, and it will work as expected.